# Why is hbase returning row keys that should have all cells expired

Tags: hadoop, hbase

We have a table that has a TTL of 30 days.  There are no other TTL defined for columns or cells in the table.

```
hbase(main):001:0> desc 'server_based_data'
Table server_based_data is ENABLED                                                                                                                                                                   
server_based_data                                                                                                                                                                                    
COLUMN FAMILIES DESCRIPTION                                                                                                                                                                          
{NAME => 'raw_data', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => '2592000 SECONDS (30 DAYS)'
, KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
```

However, when I run a scan on it, it seems that it's finding/running into rowkeys that should have all cells deleted due to the TTL expiring.  I know this because the timestamp is a part of the key, e.g. hash_servername_timestamp or 65_app129041.iad1.mydomain.com_1476641940

1476641940 is Oct 16, 2016.  I performed the scan for 6/26/2017 from 3pm-4pm

This is the snippet of my scan object/code to get the results to process.

```
    Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("raw_data"), Bytes.toBytes(fileType));
    scan.setCaching(500);
    scan.setCacheBlocks(false);
    scan.setTimeRange(start, end);
    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(tableName, scan, MTTRMapper.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, job);
```

My job fails (I think) because too many map jobs fail/are killed.  Below is a snippet from one of the logs of the failed map jobs.

> Error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException:
>   Failed after attempts=36, exceptions: Wed Jun 28 13:46:57 PDT 2017,
>   null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=120000,
>   callDuration=120301: row '65_app129041.iad1.mydomain.com_1476641940'
>   on table 'server_based_data' at region=server_based_data

I tried manually getting the contents of a few of the rows but nothing returns (as expected)

```
get 'server_based_data', '65_app129041.iad1.mydomain.com_1476641940'
COLUMN                                             CELL                                                                                                                                              

0 row(s) in 0.2900 seconds
```

My questions are:

1. Why are these keys showing up in the scan?  They shouldn't show up because they don't fall between the start and end times and because the TTL has expired.
2. How do I debug where these keys are coming from since getting the rowkey from the table yields 0 rows returned.
3. The problem rows aren't the same from test run to test run.  I ran my program back to back to back and each time, the problem rows are different.  There are some that are the same between each of the runs but they are not 100% the same.